# Terminal stops working on MacOs after opening gedit

Tags: macos, terminal, gedit

I have MacOs 10.14 and I installed gedit on my Mac via HomeBrew . When I open gedit typing :

```
gedit nameoffile
```

Terminal stops responding to commands. 
The only thing I can do in order to use Terminal again is to close gedit and terminate the session of  Terminal and reopen it. 
Is there anything I can do to solve this ?

*** I managed to find a solution for not closing gedit when I terminate the session of Terminal : I have to open gedit with

```
sudo gedit nameoffile
```

However also in this way Terminal stops responding to any command ...

Comment: What do you mean by "terminal stops responding to commands"? When you run a command from terminal, the command takes over. When you close gedit, your terminal should continue to the next prompt. You can send a command to the background when starting it by adding & to the end: `gedit nameoffile &`. You can read more here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes

Comment: What I mean is that I can type whatever I want but it doesn't respond to any command

Comment: when you close gedit (but not terminate the terminal session) does it show you a prompt? (by default some text followed by `$`)

Comment: @ aiguofer When I close gedit Terminal doesn't show the prompt . That is my problem in fact. The only thing I can do for what I know so far is reopen Terminal

Comment: what if you add `&` to the end of the command like I showed? or if you press `Ctrl-Z` when you close gedit? It's possible when you close gedit that you only closed the window but the process continues running for some reason.

Comment: Thank you @ aiguofer! Ctrl-Z solved my problems . However is it possible to continue using terminal while using Gedit ?

Comment: Sure, I added an answer explaining this. Feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Yes sure! Sorry I am new to Stackoverflow...=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a command from terminal, the command takes over. It's possible that after you close the `gedit` window, the process continues to run for some reason.

You can send a command to the background when starting it by adding `&` to the end:

```
gedit nameoffile &
```

This should instantly bring you back to the prompt when the process starts.

Alternatively, you could pause the process by hitting `Ctrl-Z`, then do a variety of things with that process like: kill it using `kill`, unpause the process and send it to the background using `bg`, bring it back to the foreground using `fg`, see list of running jobs with `jobs` and more.

You can read more about how terminal processes work [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes)